# Warning: Cannot update a component (yyyyy) while rendering a different component (FormSpy). To locate the bad setState() call inside FormSpy

Tags: react-final-form

```
<FormSpy subscription={{ values: true }}>
{({ values, form }) => {
if (values.departamentoNacimiento !== idDepartamento) 
{
setIdDepartamento(values.departamentoNacimiento)
form.change('municipioNacimiento')
}             
return null; }}    
</FormSpy>
```

my code is obove  can anyone help me. I have tried to solve it, but nothing is working. i got this Warning: Cannot update a component (Form) while rendering a different component (FormSpy). To locate the bad setState() call inside FormSpy

I try use formSpy also as an callback but form.change is not working.

```
<FormSpy   subscription={{ form: true }}   
onChange={props => {props.form.change('municipioNacimiento')}} />
```